# I'm having trouble positioning two images alongside each other in an overlay window

Tags: html, css

I'm building an overlay window and have two images that I need to position alongside each other horizontally. I have tried a few different styles and structures but can't seem to get the "subs" image alongside to the right of the "per-year"image.

This is basically where i'm at now:

```css
.per-year {
  display: block;
  max-height: 200px;
}

.subs {
  display: inline-block;
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="_rmModalContentContainer">

  <img src="logo-img" alt="" class="ellogo" >
  <p class="offer-headline">Overlay headline goes here</p>
  <div>
  <img src="image1" class="per-year">
  <img src="image2" class="subs">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add `display: inline-block` to the `per-year` class as you have currently set this to a block element.

```css
.per-year {
  display: inline-block;
  max-height: 200px;
}
.subs {
  display: inline-block;
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="_rmModalContentContainer">

  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" class="ellogo">
  <p class="offer-headline">Overlay headline goes here</p>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="per-year">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="subs">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also worth mentioning, if you're trying to position two images next to eachother, both with a width of 50% (or simply the same in pixels), you'll find out that with your current HTML this will not work. This has to do with the fact that you have a newline in your HTML after the first image. Removing this will also make it work this way.